# unfortunately <applicationName> has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, crash

So i don't know what the rules are here about double posts, anywho i didn't get follow up support on my other question.. anywho my problem is stated, heres my logcat

```
05-28 19:45:03.464: I/ActivityManager(274): Start proc xela.kasea.flyffresell for activity xela.kasea.flyffresell/.Main: pid=793 uid=10046 gids={50046, 1028}
05-28 19:45:03.474: D/dalvikvm(793): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-28 19:45:04.154: I/ARMAssembler(36): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008001_00000000 [ 89 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x41548840:0x415489f8] in 564149 ns
05-28 19:45:04.294: D/dalvikvm(793): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 6% free 2642K/2784K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
05-28 19:45:04.294: I/dalvikvm-heap(793): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.318MB for 714016-byte allocation
05-28 19:45:04.334: D/dalvikvm(793): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3337K/3484K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
05-28 19:45:04.414: I/Tag2(793): This is my error msg
05-28 19:45:04.414: D/AndroidRuntime(793): Shutting down VM
05-28 19:45:04.414: W/dalvikvm(793): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xela.kasea.flyffresell/xela.kasea.flyffresell.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at xela.kasea.flyffresell.Main.onCreate(Main.java:31)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  ... 11 more
05-28 19:45:04.433: W/ActivityManager(274):   Force finishing activity xela.kasea.flyffresell/.Main
05-28 19:45:04.743: I/WindowManager(274): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{41792b40 ActivityRecord{418a4ce0 u0 xela.kasea.flyffresell/.Main}} appWin=Window{41943b50 u0 Starting xela.kasea.flyffresell} drawState=4
05-28 19:45:04.743: W/WindowManager(274): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (400x800) to layer 21010
05-28 19:45:05.133: D/AlertService(580): Beginning updateAlertNotification
05-28 19:45:05.214: D/AlertService(580): No fired or scheduled alerts
05-28 19:45:05.263: W/ActivityManager(274): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{418a4ce0 u0 xela.kasea.flyffresell/.Main}
05-28 19:45:05.593: D/AlertService(580): Scheduling next alarm with AlarmScheduler. sEventReminderReceived: null
05-28 19:45:05.853: D/AlarmScheduler(580): No events found starting within 1 week.
05-28 19:45:06.503: I/Process(793): Sending signal. PID: 793 SIG: 9
05-28 19:45:06.513: I/ActivityManager(274): Process xela.kasea.flyffresell (pid 793) has died.
```

and heres my main.java. Note: i am only using one class.

```
package xela.kasea.flyffresell;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText perin, amountPrUnit, buy, sell;
    ToggleButton lazy;
    Button clear, submit, ret;
    double ans, subAnswer;
    TextView pEarned, tAmount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        Log.i("Tag2", "This is my error msg");
        initalizer();
        lazy.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        ret.setOnClickListener(this);
        /*String a = perin.getText().toString();
        String b = amountPrUnit.getText().toString();
        String c = buy.getText().toString();
        String d = sell.getText().toString(); */
    }

    private void initalizer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        perin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHowRich);
        amountPrUnit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmountPrUnit);
        buy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBuying);
        sell = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSellingPrUnit);
        lazy = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbBuying);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
        ret = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReturn);
        pEarned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEarned);
        tAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        /*int a = Integer.parseInt(perin.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(amountPrUnit.getText().toString());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(buy.getText().toString());
        int d = Integer.parseInt(sell.getText().toString());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a = Integer.parseInt(perin.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(amountPrUnit.getText().toString());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(buy.getText().toString());
        int d = Integer.parseInt(sell.getText().toString());
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bClear:
            perin.setText("");
            amountPrUnit.setText("");
            buy.setText("");
            sell.setText("");
            lazy.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case R.id.bReturn:
            setContentView(R.layout.display);
            break;
        case R.id.bSubmit:
            pEarned.setText(c*d-(a-(b*c)));
            tAmount.setText(c*d+(a-(a-(b*c))));
            setContentView(R.layout.finish);
            break;
        case R.id.tbBuying:
            if (lazy.isChecked()){
            buy.setText("");
            double subAnswer = 0;
            int ans = 0;
            subAnswer = a/b;
            ans = (int) Math.floor(subAnswer);
            /*new Integer((int) ans).toString();
            Integer.toString(answer);*/
            buy.setText(ans);;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

what this app is suppose to do is, take a couple of user inputted numbers and do some math with them.

and if you need it, heres the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xela.kasea.flyffresell"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is on line 31 of `Main.java`?

Comment: I'm assuming ur talking about the /* */ well it's basically a code text i took out, because it seemed to be incorrect :P

Comment: Your stacktrace says that you have a `NullPointerException` on that line...

Comment: i counted, and it appears that it's the ret.setOnClickListender(this);
if i may ask, whats a NullPointerException? reletivly new to java

Comment: check this link for explanation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: mullpointer basically means that it is looking for it and it is not there.

Comment: FYI, on double posts: Unless your question has been closed or you are planning a drastic reworking that would change its meaning you should probably edit the original one to make it clearer, more concise or ask in a different way. The edit itself will 'bump' it up to the top of the question list again. You should however now go and delete the first one if you can. If you cannot, then vote it as a duplicate of this so future readers can follow it here.

Comment: Back to the question at hand though, please post your `res/layout/display.xml` so we can check that too.

Comment: Yes, please do not double post like this. It is a good way to get yourself question banned.

Answer (score 1):

I think this comment from the user requires an answer that explains the fundamental topic of what `null` is in Java:

> if i may ask, whats a NullPointerException?

`null` pointer means that you are trying to manipulate an `Object` variable that does not have any memory allocated to it. The `NullPointerException` is Java's way of telling you: "Hey, the variable that you are trying to manipulate (i.e. set a listener to) is pointing to no memory location; there was no `Object` instantiated for this variable or it was already garbage collected. You are trying to go to use the bathroom of a building that hasn't been built yet."

The stacktrace is nice (you should be friends with him) and tells us in which line of our code the `Exception` is thrown:

```
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at xela.kasea.flyffresell.Main.onCreate(Main.java:31)
```

This means that you need to go and check that line of code and figure out which variable is `null`. Most modern IDE's have the option of introducing breakpoints that allow you to see a variable's state at runtime. Once you know which variable is `null` you can more easily figure out why. So in your case, the line causing problems is line 31 of `Main.java`. From the comments we know you said that line is:

```
ret.setOnClickListender(this);
```

That leave us with one option; `ret` has to be `null`. Then we ask ourselves:

> What can happen, under normal conditions, that can make ret be `null`?

1) The variable is not initialized; we forgot to initialize it. Not our case.

2) The variable was garbaged collected. Not our case.

3) Something went wrong when we tried to initialize our variable. Probably our case.

In this case, we do not initialize the variable by calling the constructor of some class, we do it via a method (i.e. `findViewById()`). This method takes an `int` that should be the `id` of the `View` we want to set `ret` to, and it either returns `null` or the `View` in question. So, if thought this out correctly, the error probably is that we used the wrong id.

This answer is more to show a thinking pattern rather than an actual solution since there really is not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: I figured out the problem, but this leads me with an entierly new problem..

the problem was that the ret variable was made for a return button, on another .xml then the one that i have currently setcontentview to. This make it go haywire.. but how can i set it to the other .xml? both of the xml's are going to be used. If you go down to onClick method, you see under bReturn i plan on changing the content view..

Comment: @user3672215 Don't...don't change the layout. Use one layout for this `Activity` then change activities when you need to. It sounds like you have a design problem which explaining here will get too complicated. To get the best help, accept the answer which helped solve this problem then post a new question with the relevant information, code, and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `logs` you have a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) in the line
`xela.kasea.flyffresell.Main.onCreate(Main.java:31)`

May be one of the buttons `clear, submit, ret, lazy` might be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message:

```
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 19:45:04.425: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at xela.kasea.flyffresell.Main.onCreate(Main.java:31)
```

the problem must be the button  "`bReturn`" inside your layout

```
 ret = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReturn);
```

probably doesn´t exist.

Update: well i found the problem, why load the contentview again when you click the bReturn button?:

```
case R.id.bReturn:
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
```

Comment: Please post your .xml file. You might be referencing the wrong `id` for the `View`.

Comment: I've double checked, it and it seems perfectly fine